# Does pulling out a grey hair make more grow?

Tags: medical-science, hair

I remember my mother telling me not to let other people yank any gray hairs or else more will come in its place. It has always stuck to me but wondering if it's true.

Comment: Why the -1? Can anyone let me know what I did wrong so as not to repeat it in the future?

Comment: Not sure why this is given down-vote without a comment. If this is the way older members welcome new members the forum would be dead in minutes. This claim is very common and should not need a reference ... just with a simple Google search with "pulling gray hair makes more" you can find many of such claims

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks @Tanmoy Since it wasn't asked before when I searched for it here, thought it was ok. 

I'm just skeptical of websites found in search engines. Don't know how authoritative they are even if they have the word 'hair' in the URL. 

Will the question be closed then?

Comment: I did not down vote, but the probable reason is that I can't really find any notable *claim* here. Sure, there are plenty of hits on Google - *all asserting it's a false claim!*. So while it's a notable saying, I have a hard time convincing myself it's a claim at all.

Comment: @Sklivvz: well, but it is a very common popular belief (at least where I come from)... True, there is a lot of websites asserting the contrary, but a quick look through them did not show any reference to their claim either...

Comment: @nico In this case it's probably OK; however, one of the reasons we want *real* claims is to avoid addressing straw men: misrepresentations of claims that are easily debunked versus the real claim. Once this question is allowed, for example, any other very similar questions are likely to be closed as dupes - so we want to make sure we address the real thing here :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz: good point

Comment: I always heard it like this: "if you pluck a gray hair, two will grow back it its place"

Comment: @Sklivvz doesn't that mean we should close all the evolution denial, anti-vax, homeopathic meds, magic bracelet, climate change, and cell-phone radiation questions since all are easily debunked

Comment: Balding man repeatedly pulls hair out and ends up with thick mane of silver hair. I say go for it Dad!

Comment: No, the cells that are forming a hair follicule are connected with the other follicules and can pass the message, but  certainly not about the ammount of air molecules in the hair ;) Check my answer for more details.